# SpringFramework: set bean name programmatically

Tags: java, spring

For springframwork based application, when using xml to declare beans, bean id can be configured by passing a unique value and even a parameter and then solve the value at runtime.

Now I hope to replace all xml configuration to java annotation.

Say I want to create two database beans with different id.

```
bean.xml
<bean id="A.database" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>   

<bean id="B.database" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

Then I optimize the upper code to one bean with two property file for two application

```
bean.xml
<bean id="${appName.database}"   class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean> 

applicationA.properties    
appName.database=A.database

applicationB.properties
appName.database=B.database
```

The whole application is composed of "framework" module which provides beans common for each application, like database bean, jdbcTemplate bean, and "application" module which provides property value for placeholder and initializes beans with unique id. So even if I start multiple application at the same time, they will find corresponding bean from the context.

Generally speaking, I hope to do

```
@Bean(name = "${beanName}")
public ABean getBean() {}
```

and resolve ${beanName} at application level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reading SpringFramwork document, I found the answer: BeanNameGenerator

NameGenerator.class

```
public class NameGenerator implements BeanNameGenerator{

@Override
public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition,
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    if(definition.getBeanClassName().contains("Toto")) {
        return "toto";
    }
    return return definition.getBeanClassName();
    }
}
```

AppConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.domain"}, nameGenerator = NameGenerator.class)
public class Config {
}
```

Domain class with @Component

```
@Component
public class Toto {
    private int id;
}
```

BootApplication with domain bean name : toto

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(
            DemoApplication.class, args);
    for (String name : ctx.getBeanNamesForType(Toto.class)) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a suitable solution for the problem as it's stated in your question. However, my feeling is that the problem itself needs some second thought.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu To be honest, I'm agree with you. But I'm not the chief who can make the decision and this is only one of many boring conception which is not standard, nor are those solutions. That's why I'm leaving this company. But from another side, I'm glad to know this function of spring, even though that's not really useful. I learned to read the document carefully. So, not too bad.

Comment: Is it possible to return the beanName based on a property. I would like to make it property driven as opposed to hardcoding to "toto".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow that type of approach create multiple configuration classes you annotated with different Spring [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).

At start up you can pass a parameter on which profile to use and hence what beans to load within the associated profile.

A more efficient way to do it is use the same property naming convention across all application .properties files. Set a parameter placeholder for the file name which resolves to a JVM arg passed at runtime which is loaded by the[@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation.

There's no need to have duplicate beans defined for different environments if it's just properties that are changing.

Comment: hi, I understand your solution, and it is efficient for modifying the **properties** of beans with the **same name** at different application context. But I want to achieve is to give different **bean id**/**bean name** and this is often decided by the bean method name or name value of bean.

Comment: Do you see that having different bean names for the same way for setting up beans, just with different properties might be inefficient?

Comment: well, that is not what I can decide and change. In fact all the application are running at Liferay context, that's why there will be multiple beans with different ids and properties, because there will be multiple applications requiring for the same beans, like datasource bean, etc. that's why I need a different id to pass different properties.