# javax.inject.Named with dynamic name

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 4 based application and using `@Named` annotation.

```
@Named("test")
public class DocumentMapper implements Mapper<Test> {
```

Here, the name **test** for the Named annotation is hardcoded. Is it possible to make it property driven as opposed to hardcoding the name?

I tried the below:

```
public class NameGenerator implements BeanNameGenerator {

   public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
     if(definition.getBeanClassName().contains("DocumentMapper")) {

            return "test";
        }
   }
}
```

Here, I want to return the bean name based on property. How can I inject my property config class?

Comment: I think it's possible if it's in a constant variable, try this :  `@Named(DocumentMapper.BEAN_NAME) ` where BEAN_NAME is a `public static final String BEAN_NAME ="test"; `

Comment: Yes, We are using this way. But, I want this property driven as opposed to maintain in a Constant name

Comment: are the use of @Named annotation mandatory in the context of your project ?

Comment: take a look at this [QA : set bean name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797420/springframework-set-bean-name-programmatically) , it should work the same as for @Component

Comment: Yes, @Named annotation is mandatory.

Comment: I tried the link. But, here also it cannot be based on the prop file.

Comment: No you can bind to the Environment and then retrieve the prop you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If your goal is to register bean (with a custom bean name) programmatically

You can use the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface which is :

> Extension to the standard BeanFactoryPostProcessor SPI, allowing for
>   the registration of further bean definitions before regular
>   BeanFactoryPostProcessor detection kicks in. In particular,
>   BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor may register further bean
>   definitions which in turn define BeanFactoryPostProcessor instances.

And example would be (here I want to register `MyBean` class with a name from `bean.name` property):

```
@Component
public class BeanDefinitionRegistryPP implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {
     private Environment env;

     @Override
     public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env=environment;
     }

     @Override
     public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
         GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition= new GenericBeanDefinition();
         beanDefinition.setBeanClass(MyBean.class);
         registry.registerBeanDefinition(env.getProperty("bean.name"), beanDefinition);
     }

     @Override
     public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // no code
     }
}
```

Comment: It works great. But, not getting akka error when we instantiate using  AKKA actorOf.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356119/register-bean-with-a-custom-bean-name-programmatically.

Comment: You can see my comment in your QA