# Register bean (with a custom bean name) programmatically

Tags: java, spring, akka

My goal is to register bean (with a custom bean name) programmatically.

```
@ComponentScan({ "com.test" })
public class AppConfiguration {

    //@Bean("test-bean")
    @Bean
    public Definition definition() {
        return () -> Test.class;
    }
}

@Named
@Scope("prototype")
public class Test extends DefinitionActor<?> {
   ....
}
```

Here, I use Akka and hence I have to go with @Scope("prototype").

I don't want to hard code the bean name to test-bean for some reason.

Hence, I am using the BeanPostProcessor.

```
@Component
public class BeanDefinitionRegistryPP implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
}
```

I am getting AKKA error if I go with this way.

```
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [com.test.Test] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:181) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.19.jar:na]
```

The bean post processor work with non-Akka project. Is there any other way to set the bean name programmatically even I use prototype scope.

Comment: I've never used Akka, but by Googling I found that maybe you should create your object like this `val myObject = context.actorOf(Props(new MyClass), "instanceName")`

Comment: It is working for us with the hardcoded Bean name. But, getting the error when we try to make it programmatic with the PostProcessor.